# Как найти координаты максимального элемента матрицы?

Tags: python

```
def find_mountain(a):
  return max(map(max, a))
a = [[1, 3, 1], [3, 2, 5], [2, 2, 2]]
print(find_mountain(a))
```

понимаю как определить макс. элемент, а как найти его координаты(номер ряда и столбца)

в данном массиве макс. элемент - 5

нужно чтобы вывело кортеж в ответе такой: (1, 2)

Comment: А старомодными циклами пройти?

Comment: @MBo не получалось , да и если циклами то в строчек 10 получится + много переменных и тд

Comment: фор за 1 проход может найти все 3 значения (5,1,2). решение в ответе проходит 4 ? раза.  может ктонибудь проверить что быстрее ?

Comment: @Интик Встроенные функции быстрее, несмотря на то, что с их использованием нужно два прохода. Время `4.0; 0.44; 0.75` для квадратной матрицы 4000x4000, и использования for, ответов Danis и Zhihar соответственно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def find_mountain(a):
  arr = max(a, key = max)
  return a.index(arr), arr.index(max(arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

можно так:

алгоритм находит ВСЕ максимальные значения (все двумерные координаты максимальных значений)

```
arr = [[1, 3, 1], [3, 2, 5], [2, 2, 2], [1, 5, 1]]

# найти максимальное значение    
max_value = max(max(arr, key=max))

# найти позиции
res = [(obj[0], obj[1].index(max_value)) for obj in enumerate(arr) if max_value in obj[1]]

print(res)
```